# Display outer div after li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the HTML like

```
<div id="abc">
  <ul>
     <li class="first">One<img src="images/plus.png" /></li>
     <li class="first">Two<img src="images/plus.png" /></li>
     <li class="first">Three<img src="images/plus.png" /></li>
     <li class="first">Four<img src="images/plus.png" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
     <h3>Title1</h3>
     <p>Title1 Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <h3>Title2</h3>
     <p>Title2 Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <h3>Title3</h3>
     <p>Title3 Description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <h3>Title4</h3>
     <p>Title4 Description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the first plus image the first div should be displayed below One. When I click on plus image near Two the second image should be displayed below Two. I tried lot of ways but no luck. Please provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show at least one of the things you tried, and we'll help you fix it. We don't just write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#abc > ul > li img').click(function(){
    var li = $(this).closest('li');
    $('#abc > div.content').eq(li.index()).toggle()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RsSLH/)

Answer (score 1):

So, let's restructure this a bit...

```
<div id="abc">
    <ul>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="#">One<img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Title1</h3>
                <p>Title1 Description</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="#">Two<img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Title2</h3>
                <p>Title2 Description</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="#">Three<img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Title3</h3>
                <p>Title3 Description</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="#">Four<img src="images/plus.png" /></a>
            <div class="content">
                <h3>Title4</h3>
                <p>Title4 Description</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And now the jQuery

```
// Assuming you don't have .content already hidden 
// in your CSS - remove the next line if you do
$('.content').hide();

// Added <a> tags wrapping the link parts
$('#abc li > a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parent('li').children('.content').toggle();
});
```

**Edit**: Here's a [fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/bp9Mf/) (http://jsfiddle.net/bp9Mf/)